# How do i start this indices question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$B = pq^2r^4$, where p, q and r are distinct prime numbers. The product of AB is a perfect cube. What is a possible value of A?
I was given this question and i have no clue where or how to start. Can someone please give me some sort of clue or show a step by step solution? Thank you!

Comment: Think about how many times a prime factor can be contained in the prime factorization of $AB$, which is a perfect cube. For example, if $p^s$ divides $AB$, then what can you say about the largest value of $s$? Use the knowledge of the prime factorization of $B$ to supply a value of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to find what is missing from $B$ to be a cube, i.e. $p$ has exponent 1 so since it is a prime number you need to multply for $p^2$ so that the prodocut is $p^3$ that is a cube, in the same way you work for $q$ and $r$, so that $A=p^2qr^2$, however it is not the uniqe solution, we can multiply the previous $A$ for any cube and still get a perfect cube for the product.

Answer (score 0):

**Strategy:**  If $AB$ is a perfect cube, then the exponent of each prime in its factorization must be a multiple of $3$.  If $A = p^aq^br^c$, then $AB = (p^aq^br^c)(pq^2r^4) = p^{a + 1}q^{b + 2}r^{c + 4}$.  Therefore, we must choose $a, b, c$ so that $a + 1$, $b + 2$, and $c + 4$ are all multiples of $3$.